# offline and online (SP 2010) version of Excel with slicer

Tags: excel, powerpivot

An user uploaded Excel with Pivot that has slicer to sharepoint document library. The data for this excel coming from SQL backend.

The browser gives following error.

"The workbook cannot be opened because it contains the following features that are not supported by Excel in the browser"
- Grouped Slicer

Question: Does this regular Pivot need to PowerPivot in order for SharePoint 2010 Excel Services to render it properly?

Excel file is in 2010 format. We are on SP 2010 (which is shipped with Excel 2010 services)

This article says it supports slicer: http://blogs.office.com/b/microsoft-excel/archive/2009/11/19/excel-services-in-sharepoint-2010-feature-support.aspx

=============== Answer here since it wont let me reply an answer for next 7 hours ====

Okay, the online version (the excel file that hosted in SharePoint Library) cannot have slicers with grouping. You can slicers but NO grouping.

I took out the grouping from slicers and republish the Excel (just regular pivot with sql being back end) and SP2010 renders the file smoothly.

Comment: I am optimistic this time. My previous posts had no reply. fingers crossed.

Comment: Rebecca, cause its quite a complex topic targeting specially to BI and KPI's part... for which personally I do not have much experience :)

Comment: I am sorry, I didnt mean to target anyone personally. I was wishing someone shed some light on this. Thank you for reply though

Comment: Yeah I know you didn't mean to target someone, but that seem to me obvious reason your questions are hard to answer :)